# Using templates and enums to do smart setters and getters

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I look for a clever way to use templates. I have a `class` named status, which could be the status of some hero or villain. He has three stats, called `strength`, `speed`, and `agility`.

Now I have a `set` function. But I don't want to declare a new function for every stat, which is in the name of DRY.
I see two options:

- I could use an enum to specify what stat I want, e.g. like `set(Stat::STRENGTH, 5)` and do a `switch` statement inside the set function.
- I can go the OOP route and make all the status parameters object which inherit something like `class StatValue` and then pass the object to `set(StatValue new_value)`. But I'd still have to check the type of the parameter to assign it the correct way.

Now I wonder if there is some smart way to do this using both enums and templates and  circumventing having to create all those classes, and instead keep it nice and clean.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum class Stat
{
    STRENGTH, SPEED, AGILITY,
};

class Status
{
public:
    template <Stat S>
    void set(int)
    {
        /* blank */
    }

    template <Stat S>
    int get(void)
    {
        /* blank */
        return 0;
    }

private:
    int strength;
    int speed;
    int agility;
};

int main(void)
{
    Status status{};

    status.set<Stat::STRENGTH>(5);
    std::cout << status.get<Stat::STRENGTH>();
}
```

One possibility I see is putting all values in a container and accessing them by the enum-base, so something like:

```
template <Stat S>
void set(int value)
{
    this->container_of_stats.at(static_cast<int>(S)) = value;
}
```

But I think this destroys the beauty of having an object, if you just all of its data members into a container. Is there other some smart way to do this?

Comment: You're over-analyzing it. If there are only 3 properties then just have 3 setters and move to the next issue. If there were hundreds of them then use `std::map` or even just an array to store the values. And move to the next issue.

Comment: This looks like over-engineering to me.  Do you plan to have arbitrarily many physical attributes in future, or is it more likely that there are only a handful?  I would just go for the simplest option and have three setter functions.  Or even put the attributes into a struct and set/get the entire struct.  If you want to abstract the individual functions idea, you could use a proxy function to switch on the enum and invoke the correct function, or even shove some lambdas into a map.  Of course, you risk worrying about code beauty so much that you never write a program.

Comment: It's less about beauty, but rather about conciseness. Having only one function makes extending and error checking easier. And let's say, I don't have 3 stats, but 10 and I do not just have stats, but also skills, of which I may have 5 for every one of the 10 stats, then you maybe understand why I don't want to write a setter and getter for every single.

Comment: `std::get<static_cast<int>(S)>(std::tie(strength, speed, agility)) = value;`

Comment: I support paddy statement, and a lot of IDE could generate setters/getters. If you want to proceed using tie(T.C. above) or tuple would be preferable and other developers would understand what was written quickly.